# Why does MEANJS.ORG use a server side templating language

Tags: angularjs, meanjs

I've been looking over MEAN stack (MEANJS.ORG) specifically and trying to figure out why they use [express handlesbars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars) as a server side view engine? If your using the MEAN stack, I would assume your trying to push most things to the client... AngularJS and not a server side templating language? Am I missing something here...?

And, what would be the best way to have AngularJS take over all the html rendering?

Comment: It doesn't do good for SEO though. I assume that's why they might have chosen that. Having a Single page application for their main website doesn't  help in popularity among search engines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I understand what they are doing. By choosing Express Handlebars for server side template language, they are simply being somewhat opinionated and that is it. I can still easily push as much as I want to Angular. I actually kind of like that they chose Express Handlebars instead of going with the default jade/pug - not a fan. I'm still learning the MEAN stack...

-HTH helps anyone else in the same position.